# Could not execute specified command - Not able to add customer record in Quickbooks

Tags: ado.net, quickbooks

We are trying to query Customer Master for "TEST CUSTOMER", But Quickbooks is returning an error saying "The name "[TEST CUSTOMER]" of the list element is already in use."

We tried searching customer master for the above customer, but could not find it in QB. We searched the entire list of customer which includes inactive as well but no luck.

We are using RSSBUS ADO.Net Provider for integration. When we communicated to them, they said, there might me issue with the Company File.

Can you please help us resolve the issue, or tell us the cause of the issue?

-Santosh

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks has a UNIQUE constraint across the combination of (vendors, customers, employees, "other names").

So, it could be that a vendor or employee already exists with that name.

You might also check to see if the customer is marked inactive (inactive customers don't show up in default queries).